# How can I make function to accept only numeric & alphabetics in PHP POST? THANK YOU ALL

Tags: php, validation

How to write accept only numeric and alphabetics

```
    function clean_post($_POST) {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
             $cleaned_value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
             $cleaned_value = str_replace('(','', $cleaned_value);
             $h_cleaned_array[$key] = $cleaned_value;
        }
        return $h_cleaned_array;
     }
```

Comment: have you seen http://in2.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: Look into Regular Expressions in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey maybe you can use this for check;

```
$pattern = "/[a-z0-9A-Z]+/i";
if(preg_match($pattern,$var){
   echo "It's an acceptable value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/u` in conjugation with `preg_match`.

Here's the code for sanitation -

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $s);
```

and this for validation -

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i', $s))
{
  echo "not valid alphanumeric string";
}
```

Prepare a function out of it as needed.

Comment: To note: this is *sanitisation*, not *validation*. It will make the function silently accept *anything* without complaint.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!ctype_alnum($value)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("'$value' must consist of only alphanumeric characters");
}
```

http://php.net/ctype_alnum

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to catch fish, do not just eat fish!

You can have a look at those references;

Tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Online test: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/